# How to concatenate two variables in visualforce

Tags: visualforce

Getting  errors when I try to concatenate two variables value in apex:outputText tag.

For example, if I have two variables Start_Date__c and End_Date__c,  I want to display in page as below

```
Start_Date__c to End_Date__c

<apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM/dd/yy}">
     <apex:param value="{!a.emitCS__Start_Date__c + 'to' + a.End_Date__c}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

Answer (score 2):

The "date to date" part goes in the "value" attribute, the parameters go in to the parameters.

```
<apex:outputText value="{0,date,MM/dd/yy} to {1,date,MM/dd/yy}">
    <apex:param value="{!a.emitCS__Start_Date__c}" />
    <apex:param value="{!a.End_Date__c}" />
</apex:outputText>
```

[`apex:outputText`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm) follows the same rules as the [`MessageFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) class in Java.